# How to change Textmate R-Bundle to run JGR.app instead of R.app?

Tags: r, textmate, textmatebundles

I find JGR ([Java GUI for R](http://www.rforge.net/JGR/)) far better than the standard R Gui, but I would like to run it with Textmate, because of its project handling capabilities.

There's already a Textmate bundle for R, but I can't get it to run with JGR. (But then I know next to nothing about programming Textmate bundles...)

I tried replacing 'R' with 'JGR' in the 'run Selection in R' command:

```
# input is selection or document
rawText="`cat`"

curDir=''
if [[ ${#TM_DIRECTORY} -gt 0 ]]; then
    curDir="$TM_DIRECTORY"
fi

osascript -e 'on run(theCode)' \
          -e 'tell application "R" to activate' \
          -e 'if (item 2 of theCode) is not "" then tell application "R" to cmd "setwd('\''" & (item 2 of theCode) & "'\'')"' \
          -e 'tell application "R" to cmd (item 1 of theCode)' \
          -e 'end run' -- "$rawText" "$curDir"
```

But with no luck, this results in the following error:

```
119:120: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found """. (-2741)
```

Replacing R.app with R64.app in the same way works, though.